# php is not running sql insert

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

I'm trying to user SQL Insert from PHP, however, the database does not show the line that should be inserted.

- I know the database is successfully connected to (the code has a
  condition to check this, it will exit if unsuccessful)
- The error seems to occur with the query, as the query check fails.
- I know that other SQL statements, like SELECT, work correctly.
- I have triple checked the table name and the field names, all are correct

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
<?php
    $dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/Project6/phptest/SampleUsers.accdb";
    $connection = odbc_pconnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=" .$dbName, ";", ";");
    if ($connection != true){ exit; };

    $query_string = "INSERT INTO Posts1 (Body, [User ID], [Timestamp]) VALUES ('My poem', 'Andre', '10:34');";
    $result = odbc_exec ( $connection , $query_string);
    if (!$result) { exit; };

    odbc_close ( $connection );
    echo ": works :" . $_GET["post"];
?>
```

Example working code (for SELECT statement):

```
<?php
    $dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/Project6/phptest/SampleUsers.accdb";
    $connection = odbc_pconnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=" .$dbName, ";", ";");
    if ($connection != true){ exit; };
    $query_string = "SELECT Body, [User ID], Timestamp FROM Posts1";
    $results = odbc_exec ( $connection , $query_string);

    $output = array(array());
    for ($value = odbc_fetch_array($results), $i = 1; 
        $value != false; 
        $value = odbc_fetch_array($results), $i++)
    {
        $output[$i]["userinfo"] = Array("timestamp" => array_pop($value), "user" => array_pop($value));
        $output[$i]["post"] = array_pop($value);
    }

    odbc_close ( $connection );
    echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Note: I'm new to PHP and SQL

Comment: Timestamp is a reserved word, either tablenamehere.Timestamp or [Timestamp] see also http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/sql-reserved-words-HP001032249.aspx The delimiter for dates and times in MS Access is hash (#) not single quote.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the first set of code. Apparently that wasn't the main/only problem though. My 'Timestamp' field is just a string field currently.

Comment: You simply assume your queries are working properly. Why do you check for connection errors, then NEVER check for query failures? There's exactly **ONE** way for a query to succeed, and a near infinite number of ways for it to fail. Yet you assume that 1:infinity chance will always happen.

Comment: cc: @Fionnuala I am unable to recreate the issue. I copied and pasted the first block of code, adjusted the `$dbName` to point to an existing .accdb, and then ran it. It inserted the new row just fine. As for Date/Time delimiters, Access SQL will usually accept strings as well as hash-delimited date literals.

Comment: You're right, found out how to do the query check, and it does fail. I'm still not sure what to do to fix this.

Comment: @GordThompson I just realized, perhaps this is to do with the file path. When I modify the db manually, I have to run MS Access as admin, otherwise it will say I don't have permissions. I think that the PHP file is having the same issue, as it can read but not write.

Comment: That could explain it. Try setting the permissions on the *folder* (not just the .accdb *file*) to give Everyone "Modify" permissions. If that fixes it, then find out what particular User/Group needs Modify permissions on the folder.

Comment: @GordThompson the folder kept resetting itself to "read-only", when I go to the top level folder with the read-only permissions it gives me access denied for certain sub files and will not let me change it. 
I'm trying to move it to a directory in my user path, but the php script can't find it. I'm a little stuck right now

Comment: I can't seem to put the file anywhere outside of my user path, otherwise it won't let me modify it without opening it as admin. If i put it in the user path, then it can't be found. I've hit a bit of a dead, very frustrating